# communication between containers connect fail

Tags: docker

i use docker,one is for zookeeper,other is for kafka
i use docker ps
 docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
23dbed8536dc        dc62102ccd75        "/opt/startkafka.sh"     4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                                                         inspiring_nobel
8f89ce6a4b57        00088267fb34        "/opt/startzookeeper…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        2888/tcp, 192.168.1.5:2181->2181/tcp, 3888/tcp   vigorous_zhukovsky
```

kafka config connect to zookeeper is

```
zookeeper_connect=localhost:2181
```

when i docker run kafka container

> [2018-07-15 01:31:58,369] INFO Opening socket connection to server
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL
>   (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn) [2018-07-15
>   01:31:58,373] WARN Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error,
>   closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
>   (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn) java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused    at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
>     at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
>     at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
>   [2018-07-15 01:31:59,479] INFO Opening socket connection to server
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL
>   (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn) [2018-07-15
>   01:31:59,481] WARN Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error,
>   closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
>   (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn) java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused    at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
>     at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
>     at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)

i know kafka container cannot connect to zookeeper
change kafka config 
zookeeper_connect=192.168.1.5:2181

> [2018-07-15 01:35:40,833] INFO Socket connection established to
>   192.168.1.5/192.168.1.5:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn) [2018-07-15 01:35:40,836] INFO
>   Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely
>   server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting
>   reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn) [2018-07-15 01:35:42,520]
>   ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown
>   (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
>   kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for
>   connection while in state: CONNECTING     at
>   kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply$mcV$sp(ZooKeeperClient.scala:225)
>     at
>   kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply(ZooKeeperClient.scala:221)
>     at
>   kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply(ZooKeeperClient.scala:221)
>     at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:250)   at
>   kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:221)
>     at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.(ZooKeeperClient.scala:95)
>     at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1538)  at
>   kafka.server.KafkaServer.kafka$server$KafkaServer$$createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:345)
>     at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:369)     at
>   kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:202)   at
>   kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
>     at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:92)    at
>   kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala) [2018-07-15 01:35:42,523] INFO shutting
>   down (kafka.server.KafkaServer) [2018-07-15 01:35:42,525] WARN 
>   (kafka.utils.CoreUtils$) java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   kafka.server.KafkaServer$$anonfun$shutdown$5.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaServer.scala:569)
>     at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.swallow(CoreUtils.scala:85)   at
>   kafka.server.KafkaServer.shutdown(KafkaServer.scala:569)  at
>   kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:326)   at
>   kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
>     at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:92)    at
>   kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala) [2018-07-15 01:35:42,528] INFO shut down
>   completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer) [2018-07-15 01:35:42,528] ERROR
>   Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable) [2018-07-15
>   01:35:42,530] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)

i don't know how to let kafka container connect to zookeeper container,or test connectivity between containers.
thanks your any suggestion!

Comment: Is Kafka running on a different host? or is it connected to the actual localhost? Can you show the `Dockerfile`/`docker-compose.yml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in [this example](https://github.com/gten/docker-kafka-cluster/blob/6a3d8a4546a7441dc40de6a1fbc45a3c50eb938f/README.md#setting-up-a-kafka-cluster), each kafka node should reference at runtime (on docker run) the IP of the zookpeepr cluster nodes:

```
docker run -p 9092:9092 \
  -e ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=10.0.0.1:2181,10.0.0.2:2181,10.0.0.3:2181 \
  -e KAFKA_HOST=host_kafka1 -e KAFKA_PORT=9092 -e BROKER_ID=0 \
  --name kafka1 jeygeethan/kafka-cluster
```

The general idea is [expressed here](https://github.com/christiangda/docker-kafka#special-environments-variables):

If, additionally, you have an external zookeeper server called `zk-01`, then you need to pass zookeeper.connect also

```
docker run --tty --interactive --rm \
  --name kafka-01 \
  --publish 9092:9092 \
  --env SERVER__ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zk-01 \  <=============
  --env SERVER__BROKER_ID=1 \
  --env SERVER__COMPRESSION_TYPE=gzip \
  --link zk-01 \
  christiangda/kafka bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

The point remains: zookeeper is not on "localhost", but accessible through its docker container name.

Comment: Reading your solution, I tried adding a hostname in my compose file but the 2181 port still is unreachable https://stackoverflow.com/q/64314622/958373