# debezium/zookeeper port 2181 closed

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper, debezium

I have a running Zookeeper instance from the `https://hub.docker.com/r/debezium/zookeeper:1.2` image and my Compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: debezium/zookeeper:1.2
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
    networks:
      common:
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/debezium/volumes/zookeeper/data:/zookeeper/data"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/debezium/volumes/zookeeper/txns:/zookeeper/txns"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/debezium/volumes/zookeeper/conf:/zookeeper/conf"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/debezium/volumes/zookeeper/logs:/zookeeper/logs"
    environment:
      HOST_USER_ID: ${CURRENT_UID}
      HOST_GROUP_ID: ${CURRENT_GID}
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 10s
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail http://localhost:2181 || exit 1
      interval: 1m
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
```

I can see the Zookeeper server start all right:

```
5f7860484b48        debezium/zookeeper:1.2            "/docker-entrypoint.…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (health
: starting)   2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 8778/tcp, 9779/tcp   debezium_zookeeper.1.hmdxswlsmqdebqkqvkjqzxnlc
```

with the server log showing:

```
debezium_zookeeper.1.j841dv1adeab@stephane-pc    | 2020-10-12 08:45:15,032 - INFO  [main:ContextHandler@825] - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3f197a46{/,null,AVAILABLE}
debezium_zookeeper.1.j841dv1adeab@stephane-pc    | 2020-10-12 08:45:15,111 - INFO  [main:AbstractConnector@330] - Started ServerConnector@4278a03f{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
debezium_zookeeper.1.j841dv1adeab@stephane-pc    | 2020-10-12 08:45:15,112 - INFO  [main:Server@399] - Started @5046ms
debezium_zookeeper.1.j841dv1adeab@stephane-pc    | 2020-10-12 08:45:15,113 - INFO  [main:JettyAdminServer@112] - Started AdminServer on address 0.0.0.0, port 8080 and command URL /commands
debezium_zookeeper.1.j841dv1adeab@stephane-pc    | 2020-10-12 08:45:15,135 - INFO  [main:ServerCnxnFactory@135] - Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory as server connection factory
debezium_zookeeper.1.j841dv1adeab@stephane-pc    | 2020-10-12 08:45:15,145 - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@673] - Configuring NIO connection handler with 10s sessionless connection timeout, 1 selector thread(s), 8 worker threads, and 64 kB direct buffers.
debezium_zookeeper.1.j841dv1adeab@stephane-pc    | 2020-10-12 08:45:15,150 - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@686] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
debezium_zookeeper.1.j841dv1adeab@stephane-pc    | 2020-10-12 08:45:15,224 - INFO  [main:ZKDatabase@117] - zookeeper.snapshotSizeFactor = 0.33
debezium_zookeeper.1.j841dv1adeab@stephane-pc    | 2020-10-12 08:45:15,320 - INFO  [main:FileSnap@83] - Reading snapshot /zookeeper/data/version-2/snapshot.0
debezium_zookeeper.1.j841dv1adeab@stephane-pc    | 2020-10-12 08:45:15,340 - INFO  [main:FileTxnSnapLog@404] - Snapshotting: 0x0 to /zookeeper/data/version-2/snapshot.0
debezium_zookeeper.1.j841dv1adeab@stephane-pc    | 2020-10-12 08:45:15,408 - INFO  [main:ContainerManager@64] - Using checkIntervalMs=60000 maxPerMinute=10000
debezium_zookeeper.1.j841dv1adeab@stephane-pc    | 2020-10-12 08:46:10,244 - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-1:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: Len error 1195725856
debezium_zookeeper.1.j841dv1adeab@stephane-pc    | 2020-10-12 08:47:10,884 - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-2:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: Len error 1195725856
debezium_zookeeper.1.j841dv1adeab@stephane-pc    | 2020-10-12 08:48:12,599 - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-3:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: Len error 1195725856
```

But I can't connect to the published port from the host:

```
stephane@stephane-pc:~$ nmap -p 2181 localhost
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-10-12 10:50 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00033s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
2181/tcp closed eforward
```

Of course, the port is enabled in the firewall:

```
sudo ufw allow from any to any port 2181;

stephane@stephane-pc:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8500                       ALLOW IN    127.0.0.0                 
8500                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
18630                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
2181                       ALLOW IN    127.0.0.0                 
2181                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
9092                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
8500 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
18630 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
2181 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
9092 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I can connect to the running container:

```
docker-exec debezium_zookeeper.1.app5h7goosa2cpn4g06azp2xt
```

and see the server status:

```
[zookeeper@2f57d1a84ce7 ~]$ bin/zkServer.sh status
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Client port found: 2181. Client address: localhost.
Mode: standalone
```

The log does show a warning though:

```
debezium_zookeeper.1.u0koxm2njw2i@stephane-pc    | 2020-10-12 09:03:47,829 - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-2:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: Len error 1195725856
```

which seems to be a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1330).

Could this be related to my closed port issue ?

UPDATE: I also tried adding a `hostname` property as `hostname: zookeeper` to the Compose file and add the `127.0.1.1 zookeeper` entry in the `/etc/hosts` file, but the `nmap -p 2181 zookeeper` command still showed a closed port.

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the way I check for health.

```
healthcheck:
  test: /zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh print-cmd || exit 1
  interval: 1m
  timeout: 3s
  retries: 3
  start_period: 15s
```

The complete Compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: debezium/zookeeper:1.2
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
    networks:
      common:
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/debezium/volumes/zookeeper/data:/zookeeper/data"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/debezium/volumes/zookeeper/txns:/zookeeper/txns"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/debezium/volumes/zookeeper/conf:/zookeeper/conf"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/debezium/volumes/zookeeper/logs:/zookeeper/logs"
    environment:
      HOST_USER_ID: ${CURRENT_UID}
      HOST_GROUP_ID: ${CURRENT_GID}
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 256M
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 10s
    healthcheck:
      test: /zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh print-cmd || exit 1
      interval: 1m
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 15s
  kafka:
    image: debezium/kafka:1.2
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    networks:
      common:
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/debezium/volumes/kafka/data:/kafka/data"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/debezium/volumes/kafka/logs:/kafka/logs"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      HOST_USER_ID: ${CURRENT_UID}
      HOST_GROUP_ID: ${CURRENT_GID}
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper      
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 10s
    healthcheck:
      test: /kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 || exit 1
      interval: 1m
      timeout: 15s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 15s
networks:
  common:  
    external: true
    name: common
```